How to set random number for different GN
Like on image bellow I'd like to generate random number for each mesh island. I thought to separate all islands and generate buidling node on separated islands but with no luck. Any Idea will be helpful.


As we don't know the content of your node group, we can't tell the context from which to draw valid inputs, but here are few attemps:

Use the Island Index as seed
Use a Position (maybe separated X or Y) as seed.


If they don't work, you can try to use a Store Named Attribute to create an attribute with the island index before you separate the islands, and then use the Named Attribute to retrieve it as seed.

You can also use an index in your iteration as seed:

